# Native way of view apigateway documentation in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I have an **public** AWS apigateway created providing a `swagger` file.
To document the API I have added to the `swagger` the following section:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-documentation": {
"documentationParts": [
  {
    "location": {
      "type": "API"
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "This is the API description"
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "type": "METHOD",
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/foo/{bar}"
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "This is the method description"
    }
  }
]
}
```

Then I have published the documentation version 1.0 through AWS console.

Reached this point I want to give anyone the URL of my API documentation that ideally should be rendered in the browser in a nice way.

But, checking [AWS docs regarding apigateway documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-documenting-api.html) I only find one way to access to it, that is using another AWS provided API:

> http://apigateway.eu-central1.amazonaws.com/restapis/TheIdOfMyApiGateway/documentation/parts

Additionally, I should set some access keys in the request to retrieve it, making impossible for one agnostic user to simply view it in the browser setting no additional headers in the request.

Is there any way to achieve my aim?

Comment: were you able to find an answer?

Comment: Not yet. Any hint?